# What is the best way to indicate a value that has special handling in a database table?

Tags: database

## The setup.

I have a table that stores a list of physical items for a game. Items also have a hierarchical list of categories. Example base table:

Items

```
id | parent_id | is_category | name    | description  
-- | --------- | ----------- | ------- | -----------  
1  | 0         | 1           | Weapon  | Something intended to cause damage
2  | 1         | 1           | Ranged  | Attack from a distance
3  | 1         | 1           | Melee   | Must be able to reach the target with arm
4  | 2         | 0           | Musket  | Shoots hot lead.
5  | 2         | 0           | Bomb    | Fire damage over area
6  | 0         | 1           | Mount   | Something that carries a load.
7  | 6         | 0           | Horse   | It has no name.
8  | 6         | 0           | Donkey  | Don't assume or you become one.
```

The system is currently running on PHP and SQLite but the database back-end is flexible and may use MySQL and the front-end may eventually use javascript or Object-C/Swift

## The problem.

In the sample above the program must have a different special handling for each of the top level categories and the items underneath them. e.g. Weapon and Mount are sold by different merchants, weapons may be carried while a mount cannot.

What is the best way to flag the top level tiers in code for special handling?

- While the top level categories are relatively fixed I would like to keep them in the DB so it is easier to generate the full hierarchy for visualization using a single (recursive) function.
- Nearly all foreign keys that identify an item may also identify an item category so separating them into different tables seemed very clunky.

## My thoughts.

1. I can use a string match on the name and store the id in an internal constant upon first execution. An ugly solution at best that I would like to avoid.
2. I can store the id in an internal constant at install time. better but still not quite what I prefer.
3. I can store an array in code of the top level elements instead of putting them in the table. This creates a lot of complications like how does a child point to the top level parent. Another id would have to be added to the table that is used by like 100 of the 10K rows.
4. I can store an array in code and enable identity insert at install time to add the top level elements sharing the identity of the static array. Probably my best idea but I don't really like the idea of identity insert it just doesn't feel "database" to me. Also what if a new top level item appears. Maybe start the ids at 1Million for these categories?
5. I can add a flag column "varchar(1) top_category" or "int top_category" with a character or bit-map indicating the value. Again a column used on like 10 of 10k rows.

As a software person I tend to fine software solutions so I'm curious if their is a more DB type solution out there.

Comment: Isn't the "top category" identified by the fact that it doesn't have a parent? So parent_id should be NULL for those and you can easily identify through the `null` value in that column

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Love the handle! True but the special handling is different for each top-level element. So I would still need to differentiate them from each-other. I'll try to clarify the question to include this information.

Comment: Are you able to create other tables, and/or modify your existing one; or are you working with a predefined schema?  If you have flexibility of creating additional tables, I'd create a table that stores the information on handling scenario, then link to them via a fkey reference in your current table.

Comment: @Daileyo It's a small personal project so I can do anything needed. If additional tables would help would love to hear how :). My original desigen was going to seperate item_type from item but that created another set of issues as a player may be able to use a specific item or anything in a category and I didn't like storing those id's seperatly.

Comment: You could keep the items all in the same table still.  I'm thinking you just create a new table like actions.   By referencing that via fkey in your items table you have flexibility of defining actions for all items, not just the top 3.  Then, from your code, you data models can be specific for the top 3 to include data referenced by the fkey, but not for the rest.

Comment: @Daileyo not sure I understand what an "actions" table is but would love to hear more.

Comment: I'll post a jsfiddle example of what I mean later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202423/discussion-between-danielson317-and-daileyo).

Answer (score 1):

[Original table, with a join to actions](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/191a7/2).

Yes, you can put everything in a single table.  You'd just need to establish unique rows for every scenario.  This [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/047399/5) gives you an example... but **IMO** it starts to become difficult to make sense of.  This doesn't take care of all scenarios, due to not being able to do full joins (just a limitation of sqlfiddle that is awesome otherwise.)

**IMO**, breaking things out into tables makes more sense.  Here's [another example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/047399/1) of how I'd start to approach a schema design for some of the scenarios you described.

The base tables themselve look clunky, but it gives so much more flexibility of how the data is used.

**tl;dr analogy ahead**

A datase isn't a list of outfits, organized in rows. It's where you store the cothes that make up an outfit.

So the clunky feel of breaking things out into separate tables, is actually the benefit of relational datbases.  Putting everything into a single table feels efficient and optimized at first... but as you expand complexity... it starts to become a pain.

Think of your schema as a dresser.  Drawers are you tables.  If you only have a few socks and underware, putting them all in one drawer is efficient.  But once you get enough socks, it can become a pain to have them all in the same drawer as your underware.  You have dress socks, crew socks, ankle socks, furry socks.  So you put them in another drawer.  Once you have shirts, shorts, pants, you start putting them in drawers too.

The drive for putting all data into a single table is often driven by how you intend to use the data.

Assuming your dresser is fully stocked and neatly organized, you have several potential unique outfits; all neatly organized in your dresser.  You just need to put them together.  Select and Joins are you you would assemble those outfits.  The fact that your favorite jean/t-shirt/sock combo isn't all in one drawer doesn't make it clunky or inefficient.  The fact that they are separated and organized allows you to:
1.  Quickly know where to get each item
2.  See potential other new favorite combos
3.  Quickly see what you have of each component of your outfit

There's nothing wrong with choosing to think of outfit first, then how you will put it away later.  If you only have one outfit, putting everything in one drawer is way easier than putting each pieace in a separate drawer.  However, as you expand your wardrobe, the single drawer for everything starts to become inefficient.

You typically want to plan for expansion and versatility.  Your program can put the data together however you need it.  A well organized schema can do that for you.  Whether you use an ORM and do model driven data storage; or start with the schema, and then build models based on the schema; the more complex you data requirements become; the more similar both approaches become.

Answer (score 0):

A relational database is meant to store entities in tables that relate to each other. Very often you'll see examples of a company database consisting of departments, employees, jobs, etc. or of stores holding products, clients, orders, and suppliers.

It is very easy to query such database and for example get all employees that have a certain job in a particular department:

```
select *
from employees
where job_id = (select id from job where name = 'accountant')
and dept_id = select id from departments where name = 'buying');
```

You on the other hand have only one table containing "things". One row can relate to another meaning "is of type". You could call this table "something". And were it about company data, we would get the job thus:

```
select * 
from something
where description = 'accountant'
and parent_id = (select id from something where description = 'job');
```

and the department thus:

```
select * 
from something
where description = 'buying'
and parent_id = (select id from something where description = 'department');
```

These two would still have to be related by persons working in a department in a job. A mere "is type of" doesn't suffice then. The short query I've shown above would become quite big and complex with your type of database. Imagine the same with a more complicated query.

And your app would either not know anything about what it's selecting (well, it *would* know it's something which is of some type and another something that is of some type and the person (if you go so far as to introduce a person table) is connected somehow with these two things), or it would have to know what description "department" means and what description "job" means.

Your database is blind. It doesn't know what a "something" is. If you make a programming mistake some time (most of us do), you may even store wrong relations (A Donkey is of type Musket and hence "shoots hot lead" while you can ride it) and your app may crash at one point or another not able to deal with a query result.

Don't you want your app to know what a weapon is and what a mount is? That a weapon enables you to fight and a mount enables you to travel? So why make this a secret? Do you think you gain flexibility? Well, then add food to your table without altering the app. What will the app do with this information? You see, you must code this anyway.

Separate *entity* from *data*. Your entities are weapons and mounts so far. These should be tables. Then you have instances (rows) of these entities that have certain attributes. A bomb is a weapon with a certain range for instance.

Tables could look like this:

- person (person_id, name, strength_points, ...)
- weapon (weapon_id, name, range_from, range_to, weight, force_points, ...)
- person_weapon(person_id, weapon_id)
- mount (mount_id, name, speed, endurance, ...)
- person_mount(person_id, mount_id)
- food (food_id, name, weight, energy_points, ...)
- person_food (person_id, food_id)
- armor (armor_id, name, protection_points, ...)
- person_armor <= a table for m:n or a mere person.id_armor for 1:n
- ...

This is just an example, but it shows clearly what entities your app is dealing with. It knows weapons and food are something the person carries, so these can only have a maximum total weight for a person. A mount is something to use for transport and can make a person move faster (or carry weight, if your app and tables allow for that). Etc.